# Android How am I supposed to change size of actionbar settitle text?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change my action bar title text size. How am I supposed to do it?

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.tg_logo_new);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.show();
    actionBar.setTitle("Header");
```

Comment: I think what helps is using a Toolbar, not using `setTitle` but rather just use your own text view inside the Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this ..

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(" <b> YOUR TITLE </b> "));
```

in fromHtml() you can use any tag instead `<b>`. **you can also use `<h2>,<h3>, .., <h6>`** if you want bigger size.

that's it
You can do it

```
    b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (b != null) { 
          String Description = b.getString("Description"); 
          android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
          actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<b>" +Description+ "</b>"));
    }
```

Comment: i m actually getting those values from other activity and setting it like this
actionBar.setTitle(Description);
how am i supposed to do it your way?

Comment: Can u show me the code where you are getting the description .?

Comment: b = getIntent().getExtras();

  if (b != null) {

   Description = b.getString("Description");
//description is a string globally

}

actionBar.setTitle(Description);

Comment: Hi i want a text size of 12dp <h1> size is very big

Comment: `<h1>` have biggest size. and it get smaller with `<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>` .

Comment: ya.....i m sorry i was supposed to say <h6>...it is quite big how am i supposed to go smaller than <h6> i want a precise of 10dp text

Comment: There is no more possibility ..But for description you can use subTitle of actionbar

Answer (score -1):

Try this, will solve your issue:

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Theme.YourTheme">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

It required API 11 and above

Comment: Nope it is showing error this is my xml code

<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: its not working only changing the color of action bar elements